# Horizontal Wordpress-Theme How to achieve?

Tags: wordpress, themes

I wanted to create a horizontal based wp theme.
Something like this one (http://www.lena-meyer-landrut.de)

What would be the best starting point to do that?

Every menuitem(category) is a single post? A custom field? a page? Something else?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If the content doesn't change too often, you can use pages.

But with that theme you would have to write multiple wordpress loops, this code can get quite messy.

Create a loop for each "page" that shows up on the page.

---

Another way...you could hard-code the design + jQuery sliding.

Then for the plain content sections you could create multiple "sidebars" and put a sidebar where each content part is...the user could then edit their own content with a text widget.

http://www.quickonlinetips.com/archives/2007/11/how-to-create-multiple-dynamic-sidebars-for-wordpress-widgets/

---

Custom posts are okay, but if you are writing more than 1 custom post per page/post, then it can get quite cluttered...

Answer (score 0):

I think the best option for you would be to build your site based off one of the frameworks of an existing horizontal theme...

Here is the best information I found: 
http://wordpress.org/support/topic/horizontal-way-for-wordpress?replies=13

Direct link to the old "horizontal way" theme for wordpress: 
http://www.thehorizontalway.com/download/THW_template_0.6.zip

Here is another base theme to base your site off of:
http://wordpress.org/extend/themes/wplatformer