# side scrolling wordpress site

Tags: html, css, wordpress, layout, horizontal-scrolling

I have been asked to design a side scrolling site for Wordpress similar to this
[site](http://alecsoth.com/photography/projects/broken-manual/).  Each post is positioned side by side on the page.

Im trying to work out if there is a line of PHP that i can add to page.php that will allow a normal vertical scrolling site to horizontal scroll ?? as far as I'm aware there is no jQuery used . . . . .

I've looked for countless amounts of Wordpress themes but can't seem to find the relevant piece of php for horizontal-scrolling. It seems to be quite a common layout for UK based illustrators/graphic designers. Does anyone have any ideas how to achieve this ??

thanks

Comment: Retagging. This is a HTML / CSS question, not a PHP one.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Horizontal Wordpress-Theme How to achieve?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4518532/horizontal-wordpress-theme-how-to-achieve)

Answer (score 1):

https://css-tricks.com/how-to-create-a-horizontally-scrolling-site/

the DEMO...

https://css-tricks.com/examples/HorzScrolling/

Is quite good - although could be more intuitive with anchors & arrows

Comment: This is almost certainly the way to go. Sooo nice that when you scroll "up" and "down" it does what you expect (goes side to side). Never ever ever implement a side scrolling design that doesn't take up/down scroll into account (and turn it into side to side. Your design should only scroll along a single axis unless it absolutely *has to* scroll along both...

Answer (score 0):

Give your body (or for instance a wrapper div) an explicit width, either via CSS (fixed, see below) or JavaScript (dynamic and for instance depending on the number of articles). Then float your articles left and give them an explicit width as well.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<style>
    body { width: 8000px; }
    .article { float: left; width: 800px; }
</style>
<body>
  <div class="article">...</div>
  ... 
  <div class="article">...</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this theme:
http://thethemefoundry.com/shelf/

Otherwise you'll have to digg into CSS for that effect.